# ruby with tk support

Tags: ruby, tk-toolkit, nix

I am following a [programming languages course](https://www.coursera.org/learn/programming-languages-part-c) that requires `ruby` with `tk` support. My laptop runs `nixos`. Simply adding tk and ruby to my system packages doesn't cut it. Creating a nix-shell with both doesn't either. How would I construct a derivation where ruby is compiled with tk support?

`shell.nix`

```
{ pkgs ? import <nixpkgs> {} }:

with pkgs;

let
  myRuby = ruby_2_3.overrideAttrs (old: {
    configureFlags = [
      "--with-tcl-dir=${tcl}"
      "--with-tk-dir=${tk}"
      "--enable-tcl-thread"
      "--enable-pthread"
    ];
    buildInputs = [
      ruby_2_3
      zlib
      gdbm
      libffi
      openssl
      readline
    ];
    propagatedBuildInputs = [
      tk
      tcl
    ];

  });

in
  mkShell {
    buildInputs = [ myRuby tk tcl ];
  }
```

`test.rb`

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby
 require 'tk'
 root = TkRoot.new do
   title "Ruby/Tk Test"
 end
 Tk.mainloop
```

Comment: I can't speak for NixOS specifically, but I believe Ruby/tk is no longer maintained (for a few years now). The GUI situation with Ruby is appalling, without much positive outlook. There is some decent bindings for Qt4 which are probably the most widely used when GUI is needed, but even they are getting outdated, being built on top of a older technology. Sadly, trying to implement a modern GUI with Ruby is a form of self-masochism.

Comment: @ForeverZer0 I'm using ruby-2.3 as per the course instructions

Comment: You could try to open an issue at https://github.com/ruby/tk , but considering that the last commit is more than 1 year old, I fear too that it is not maintained anymore. My impression is that ActiveState is still supporting it, and since they claim to support Linux too, this might be an option. Of course it means that you would also have to install the ActiveState port of Ruby and Tcl. You might want to ask first at http://code.activestate.com/lists/ruby-talk/ whether this is a feasible approach.

Answer (score 1):

I decided to just build a derivation and install it. This works!

```
{ pkgs ? import <nixpkgs> {} }:

with pkgs;

let
  myRuby = ruby_2_3.overrideAttrs (old: {
    configureFlags = [
      "--with-tcl-dir=${tcl}"
      "--with-tk-dir=${tk}"
      "--enable-tcl-thread"
      "--enable-pthread"
    ];
    buildInputs = [
      ruby_2_3
      zlib
      gdbm
      libffi
      openssl
      readline
    ];
    propagatedBuildInputs = [
      tk
      tcl
    ];

  });

in
  myRuby
```